# Why is my Corona sdk app 300 MB when i build it for Android?

Tags: android, coronasdk

The app has only 1 picture and some line of code but when i build it for android the size off the .apk is over 300 mb 
Any idea why this happen?

Comment: Well, how big is the picture...? ;-)

Comment: Check [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148628/corona-sdk-application-size-is-too-big) which seems very similar.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the .apk file to see what is in there taking up so much space?  The apk file is just a zip file, you should be able to view it's contents with any zip file viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any files/folders in your project folder ?
Corona will include all files even if you don't use them.